# Rails 4 Filter Index lists with toggle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, filter

I have created a small ticketing system for my users. I have tickets as New, In Progress and Completed. I would like to be able to toggle on the page whether the completed are hidden or shown. What is the best way to do this? The param that holds these values is `ticket.status`.

In Controller:

```
def index
    @tickets = Ticket.all

    if params[:filter_by]
        @tickets = Ticket.where(:category => params[:filter_by])
    else
        @tickets = Ticket.all
    end
end
```

In Index view:

```
<div>
<div><%= link_to "Full Listing", tickets_path %></div>
<div><%= link_to "Admin", tickets_path(:filter_by => :Administrative), {:method => :get} %></div>
<div><%= link_to "Graphics", tickets_path(:filter_by => :Graphics), {:method => :get} %></div>
<div><%= link_to "IT", tickets_path(:filter_by => :IT), {:method => :get} %></div> ||| 
<div><%= link_to "New entry", new_ticket_path %></div> ||| 
<div>
  <% if current_user.present? %>
    <%= link_to " Sign Out", sessions_path, method: :delete %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an HTML for toggle itself?

Comment: From looking at the html code I am looking at, the input is going to be a check box. From that the toggle is just dressing.

Comment: Can you update your code and include this checkbox?

Comment: That's my problem, I can write a checkbox, but as for the code for the filter, I have no clue, that is why I am asking the question I am.

Comment: You need to add a checkbox, then write a JS that catch checkbox change and send an ajax request to your rails server to update ticket's status

Answer (score 0):

How about you take a look at Ransack, SimpleForm and SimpleFormRansack? That is how I build most of my own index filters.

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

https://github.com/kaspernj/simple_form_ransack

In your controller do something like this:

```
def index
  ransack_params = params[:q] || {}
  ransack_params[:status_eq_any] ||= ["New"]

  @ransack = Ticket.ransack(params[:q])
  @tickets = @ransack.result
end
```

In your view you could do something like this:

```
<%= simple_search_form_for @ransack do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :category_eq_any, collection: ["Administrative", "Graphics", "IT"] %>
  <%= f.input :status_eq_any, collection: ["New", "Completed"] %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>

<% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

You can also show links to predefined searches like this:

```
<%= link_to "Admin", tickets_path(q: {status_eq: "Administrative"}) %>
```

Comment: This looks very useful! Quick question, I always want the buttons for the categories to function, but I want the toggle to just hide/show the completed tickets, and with the set up you gave me above it will do that?